# Found it tiring to type so many \begin and \end

Tags: macros, environments

Is there some way to get rid of the `\begin` and `\end`'s? For example, I need to type a small matrix, but I should type `\begin{matrix}...\end{matrix}`. I tried to define a macro

```
\newcommand{\matx}[1]{\begin{matrix}{{#1}}\end{matrix}}
```

but it doesn't work. Do you know if there's a LaTeX way to do it? Thank you very much!

Comment: Note the error is not because of the command definition `\begin{matrix}{{1&2}}\end{matrix}` would not work either. (But note you can not do this with AMS alignments such as `\begin{align}`)

Comment: use a powerful editor, like `vim`, for example; it does a lot of the tedious work for you

Answer (score 16):

Just delete the unnecessary braces in your definition.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\matx}[1]{\begin{matrix}#1\end{matrix}}
\begin{document}
\[
\matx{ 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 }
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

I use emacs with [AUCTeX](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/) and Ctrl-c Ctrl-e will enter the matching pairs automatically.  I'm sure vim will have a command that does likewise.

Comment: Any 1/2-decent+ editor should do this is you really want it, as do many of the TeX-specific IDEs - perhaps the OP should tell us which editor they're using.

Answer (score -4):

I would suggest the following:

```
\def \bm {\begin{matrix}} 
\def \em {\end{matrix}}
```

So that you just need to type \bm instead of \begin{matrix}

minimal code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def \bm {\begin{matrix}} 
\def \em {\end{matrix}}
\begin{document}
\[
\bm
1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 
\em
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: **Overwriting standard commands is *not* recommended.** In any case, it will not work in this case. Did you consider testing this before posting? There is a good reason that *answers*, as well as questions, should generally include Minimal Working Examples!

Comment: This works for me. I just posted the minimal code

Comment: `\emph{Emphasise this}`.